# Is using a global object as a COM class factory legal?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, factory-pattern

In an out-proc COM server I need a class factory that I will pass to `CoRegisterClassObject()`. `CreateInstance()` will only use `new` to create object instances and need no stored data. `LockServer()` will modify shared lock counter not specific to the factory instance.

So in fact I don't need to store any distinct data inside factory and having only one object will do just fine. Also I don't want to take care of that object lifetime. This is why I'm tempted to declare the factory as a global variable (with refcount set to 1 in constructor):

```
//Server.cpp
CMyFactory factory;
```

Once I do that I'm no longer satisfied with `delete this` inside `Release()` - that code should never run under normal conditions (refcount starts at 1 and never reaches zero) and if it runs it leads to undefined behavior. So I think of removing the ref counter from the factory and implementing `AddRef()` and `Release()` like this:

```
ULONG CMyFactory::AddRef()
{
   return 1;
}
ULONG CMyFactory::Release()
{
   return 1;
}
```

So reference counting will just have no side effects, there's no `delete this`.

Will the described implementation be legal? Will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you control the process lifetime on different mean, this is accepted. delete this in this case is disaster as the object is global not a dynamic one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly legal, and even documented somewhere in the COM books.